# How to target a specific cell in a mysql query table result using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm having this problem on how I can access a specific table cell when I get the column from a mysqli_fetch_array result and storing it in a variable.

```
    $sql5 = "SELECT e.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number FROM employee e JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE e.team_team_id = '$team_id' AND (position_pos_id = 3 or position_pos_id = 4 or position_pos_id = 5 or position_pos_id = 6 or position_pos_id = 7 or position_pos_id = 8 or position_pos_id = 9 or position_pos_id = 10 or position_pos_id = 11 or position_pos_id = 13 or position_pos_id = 14 or position_pos_id = 15 or position_pos_id = 16)";

    $result5 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql5);
    $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5);

    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
        echo "<select id='testingDiv".$i."' name='employee[]' class='clonedInput'>
        <option value='".$row5['row_number'][$i]."'>" .$row5['emp_fname']. " " .$row5['emp_lname'] ."</option>";
        while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row3['emp_id'] ."'>" .$row3['emp_fname']. " " .$row3['emp_lname'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select><br>";
```

As you can see I was planning to iterate it through a counter and treat it like a 3d array but I found out that it wasn't possible. Now I'm at a lost as I don't know how to access the specific cell of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you should use the structure of the inner loop in the outer one too

```
$result5 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql5);

$i = 0;
while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {
    echo "<select id='testingDiv" . $i . "' name='employee[]' class='clonedInput'>
    <option value='" . $i . "'>" .
        $row5['emp_fname'] . " " . $row5['emp_lname'] .
    "</option>";
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row3['emp_id'] . "'>" .
                 $row3['emp_fname'] . " " . $row3['emp_lname'] .
             "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select><br>";
    $i++;
}
```

**Edit (explaination of what's going on)**

The main problem with your code is that `mysqli_fetch_array` returns a single row of the resultset, so you cannot use that result as a bidimensional array and access all the rows with the `for` loop you were using.

What you have to do is translate that outer `for` into a `while` loop, so that on each iteration you fetch a new row into that `$row5` variable. By doing that, you need to handle the counter value manually, hence that `$i++` at the end.

Regarding the translation of `$row5['row_number'][$i]` into `$i`, I guess you wanted to get the current row index. For the same reason I explained above, that instruction is wrong, because the `$row5` variable contains a single row, which most likely won't have a `'row_number'` column and definitely won't have a second dimension you can access with `$i`. The current row index however is already available in `$i` itself, so I used that counter instead.

Comment: This worked by I don't know how though like when you used the counter in the value attribute in the options tag while inside the while loop of $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5) can you explain it a bit? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @PaulJVC I added some explaination to my answer, I hope it will be enough. If not tell me what's still obscure to you.